# why is python so popular among the Online Education Sites?

Tags: python

I have been learning online lot of programming stuff these days using online sites like Udacity, Coursera, Khan Academy etc. I see most of them offer understanding of programming, understanding of Web, or several other things through python as a example language. I also learned about google app engine and found python as one of the language other than java that is supported. It is actually surprising that other popular languages or i should say more familiar languages like java, php etc are not finding their place in this category. I am asking this question as i code and understand php and java. But to go thorough these online classes i need to build an understanding of python as well. So i want to understand if learning python and its entire set of features will be useful and what in python inspires online education site as their preferred language.

Comment: Well if you all are closing it, where should i find a answer for this?

Comment: I'd say weak typing and cleaner syntax are the main advantages for beginners. It's also interpreted, which tends to be great for teaching because of the ability to immediately evaluate what you write, it avoids a lot of the boilerplate and complexity involved in e.g. C++, and its widely used in the community, so there are lots of modules available that you can just plug into your program as-is.

Comment: @Maulwurfn i can see so many meta non-programming questions on SO itself, and do u know the site where i can ask meta question if this does not qualify here.

Comment: @Moritz thanks for your answer, I also want to understand if its also widely used for production level developments like ruby or php or java is used. As i do not see people around here in community taking much about python.

Comment: through this question i aim to build an understanding as my learning of python should only for understanding of topics in online learning sites or i can apply that learning to create a widely used production level site.

Comment: @Moritz: Python is a strongly typed language, so no, weak typing is not an advantage.

Comment: @Wooble: OK, you're right. What I meant was, there's no need for explicit casting and type declarations, and the built-in types are a lot easier to get a grip of (in python, at least at a beginner's level, a string is a string, whereas in C you have to fool around with char arrays, std::string's, strcpy and such)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many reasons for why Python is so popular:

- It is easy to learn
- It has a very clean syntax
- It is good for scientific computations
- It can do many things, from desktop application to web programming
- It is available on most *nix systems by default
- It is available on many operating systems (Linux, Mac OS, Windows, ...)
- It can be used together with C.

This list can go on and on ... .